# instrumenting an "import" using java asm library

Tags: java, assembly, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I'm using the asm library for java instrumentation and I want to instrument an "import"
instruction. so that by using visitMethodInsn and INVOKEVIRTUAL i would be able to call a function from my package.
I'm aware that when I have a bytecode the linkage stage is over so I might have trouble doing so. any solution/detour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

byte code uses full package.class names.  There is no "import" equivelents at the byte code level. If you want to import a class, just use its fully qualified name.